# Hashed string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there some kind of hashed string type in MySQL?

Let's say we have a table

```
user | action  | target
-----------------------
1    | likes   | 14
2    | follows | 190
```

I don't want to store "action" as text, because it takes much space and is slow to index. Actions are likely to be limited (up to 50 actions, I guess) but can be added/removed in the future. So I would like to avoid storing all actions by numbers in PHP. I would like to have a table that handles this transparently.

For example, table above would be stored as (1,1,14), (2,2,190) internally, and keys would be stored in another table (1 = likes, 2 = follows).

```
INSERT INTO table (41, "likes", 153)
```

Here "likes" is resolved to 1.

```
INSERT INTO table (23, "dislikes", 1245)
```

Here we have no key for "dislikes" to it is added and stored internally as 3.

Possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a fixed (or reasonably fixed) set of values, then you can use an enum field. This is implemented as a bitmask internally and as a result takes a small amount of disk space. Here is an example definition:

```
CREATE TABLE enum_test (
    myEnum enum('enabled', 'disabled', 'unknown')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, with a subquery like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (23, (SELECT id FROM actions WHERE action="dislikes") , 1245)
```

This way it is possible to don't know the ID from PHP side, but only the action name, and still input it in the database as an ID

This assuming you have a 'actions' table

```
id | action
-----------
1  | like
2  | dislike
```

Comment: This is pretty. But can I create something similar to view that would allow me to write `INSERT INTO virtual_table (23, "dislikes", 1245)` which would be transformed to your example?

Comment: you could use stored functions, but that still would mean you'll have to write it differently. You could also use PHP and regular expressions to change it, but that's not how you'd want it. This is in my opinion the best option

Comment: @user1019812 you can do something to the effect of `INSERT INTO virtual_table (23, (SELECT id FROM actions WHERE action = 'dislikes'), 1245)` you wouldn't need a stored function for this but it may be more maintainable to use one in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You want a table called "actions", and a foreign key called "action_id". That is how database normalization works:

user_actions:

```
user | action_id  | target
-----------------------
1    | 1          | 14
2    | 2          | 190
```

actions:

```
id  | name    
--------------
1   | likes   
2   | follows
```

As far as making `insert into user_actions (1, 'likes', 47)` work: You shouldn't care. Trying to make your SQL pretty is a pointless pursuit; you should never actually have to write any in your application code. The database interactions should be handled by a layer of models/business objects, and their internal implementation shouldn't matter to you.

As far as making `insert into user_actions (1, 'dislikes', 47)` automatically create new records in the `actions` table: That again isn't the database's job. Your models should be handling this.

Comment: Hi meagar, I know that! This is exactly what I want to have internally. I can easily create a view that will allow to get (1, "likes", 14) tuple, but I would also like to have similar wrapper around writing.